# Extracting Windows from an Acer Recovery CD

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installation, system-recovery

I have an Acer Tablet PC that came with WIndows XP Tablet PC Edition in the form of three recovery DVDs.

Sadly, a mainboard fault put the machine out of business. I have now bought a used one from a different manufacturer that came without an operating system.

I want to install the Windows XP Tablet PC edition on it. I have a license and CD key for it. However, the Acer machine's recovery DVDs seem to contain three parts of a Norton Ghost image, and nothing else. The recovery DVD won't even start on a Non-Acer system.

- Is there any chance of extracting usable Windows XP installation files from that image? How are such image files usually made up?
- Is there any free software around that can read Norton Ghost images so I can take a peek myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a copy of Ghost handy, Ghost Explorer (I think the filename is **ghostexp.exe**) should be somewhere on the disc. If not you might be able to obtain it by downloading a trial of Ghost itself via Symantec's site.

Answer (score 2):

This is a copy of Ghost Explorer, you can use this to extract the installation files. http://www.4shared.com/file/250082829/6d738e26/Norton_Ghost_Explorer.html

Comment: On reading your and @Darth's advice, I checked the DVDs again and found an explorer program already there (no original installation files found yet, though). Still thanks @Adeel for the upload, that's very nice.